# How to skip any table column by selector in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating get value from each table row and pass to another html element by using Jquery.

**My Issue** I can't skip the last column

```
<table id="mytable"> 
    <tbody id="row">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="no">0</div></td>
            <td><a><div class="id">61</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="name" onclick="dialogbox(61)">45353</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="prices line">345345</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="ads_order line"></div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="des line">asdfasdf</div></a></td>
            <td><div class="viewed line"></div></td>
            <td><div class="status line">1</div></td>
            <td><a class="delete" onclick="deleted(61)"><div class="fa fa-times fa-3"></div></a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div id="no">1</div></td>
            <td><a><div class="id">62</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="name" onclick="dialogbox(62)">asdfasdf</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="prices line">4234240</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="ads_order line"></div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="des line">sdfsadfsadfsadfsafd</div></a></td>
            <td><div class="viewed line"></div></td>
            <td><div class="status line">1</div></td>
            <td><a class="delete" onclick="deleted(62)"><div class="fa fa-times fa-3"></div></a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div id="no">2</div></td>
            <td><a><div class="id">63</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="name" onclick="dialogbox(63)">asdfasdf</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="prices line">555</div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="ads_order line"></div></a></td>
            <td><a><div class="des line">sadfasdfas</div></a></td>
            <td><div class="viewed line"></div></td>
            <td><div class="status line">1</div></td>
            <td class="td_diable"><a class="delete" onclick="deleted(63)"><div class="fa fa-times fa-3"></div></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My **#modalAds** and another variables with initial when **tr** was clicked and pass all the values to those selector and I want to skip the last column which contain the **.td_disable** selector but it is not skip for me.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('mouseover', "table#mytable", function (){
        $("tr:not('[class^=td_diable]')").click(function () {
            $('#modalAds').modal('show');
//          var index = $("tr", $("#mytable").closest("table")).index(this); to find row index inside of table
            $("#p_name").val($(this).find("td a div.name").text());
            $("#p_price").val($(this).find("td a div.prices").text());
            $("#p_addr").val($(this).find("td a div.addr").text());
            $("#p_des").val($(this).find("td a div.des").text());prices + ads_orders + des + viewed + status);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems, you are adding a new click handler to each `tr` elemnet every time mouse is moved over the table that is not required.

Since you don't want to target the last `td`, I think it will be better to target the `td` instead of the `tr` element for the click handler.

```
$(document).on('click', "#mytable td:not(.td_diable)", function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('#modalAds').modal('show');
    $("#p_name").val($tr.find("td a div.name").text());
    $("#p_price").val($tr.find("td a div.prices").text());
    $("#p_addr").val($tr.find("td a div.addr").text());
    $("#p_des").val($tr.find("td a div.des").text());
    prices + ads_orders + des + viewed + status);
});
```

---

If you still want to target the `tr` for the click, then check whether the click had happened inside the `td.td_diable` using `event.target` like

```
$(document).on('click', "#mytable tr", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.td_diable').length) {
        return;
    }
    var $tr = $(this);
    $('#modalAds').modal('show');
    $("#p_name").val($tr.find("td a div.name").text());
    $("#p_price").val($tr.find("td a div.prices").text());
    $("#p_addr").val($tr.find("td a div.addr").text());
    $("#p_des").val($tr.find("td a div.des").text());
    //prices + ads_orders + des + viewed + status);
});
```

Comment: Your code is working for me because my html was respond my ajax so I have to call $(document) and I used tr for target click.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is $('#mytable').on('click', "td:not(.td_diable)", function () { is not work but the last one is work

Comment: @Cambodiachannel then `$(document).on('click', "#mytable td:not(.td_diable)", function () {...})`

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use **[`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** over `not()` to filter according to childen elements' attributes.

   ```
   $("tr:not(:has(.td_diable)")
   ```
2. Don't define the click inside `mouseover` handler. You can use `$("#myTable tr:not(:has(.td_diable)")` instead.
3. Instead of `[class=".."]` attribute selector, `.className` is a better selector.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the classname to the tag **tr**, not to **td**. In other words, it should be:

```
<tr class="td_diable">
    <td><div id="no">2</div></td>
    <td><a><div class="id">63</div></a></td>
    <td><a><div class="name" onclick="dialogbox(63)">asdfasdf</div></a></td>
    <td><a><div class="prices line">555</div></a></td>
    <td><a><div class="ads_order line"></div></a></td>
    <td><a><div class="des line">sadfasdfas</div></a></td>
    <td><div class="viewed line"></div></td>
    <td><div class="status line">1</div></td>
    <td ><a class="delete" onclick="deleted(63)"><div class="fa fa-times fa-3"></div></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("tr:not('[class^=td_diable]')").click` use an alternative like

```
$("td").not($("tr:last").find("td:last")).click
```

Answer (score 1):

This selector `$("tr:not('[class^=td_diable]')")` is for a `tr`. But you are applying `td_diable` for `td`.